# How to get the value of this field with queryselector?

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I'm new to programming, sorry if its obvious but I can't find the answer.
I'm doing a puppeteer bot to get values of a marketplace so I don't have to do it daily.

I'm trying document.querySelector('.FiatPrice_FiatPrice__5w_aV').value

At this website: https://app.axieinfinity.com/marketplace/axies/?auctionTypes=Sale&summer=6
but it doesn't return any value.

```
   const resultadoEth = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('.Price_Container__UAUoC.AxieCard_Price__sGl3J').value;
      });
```

Comment: Please provide the markup under the question.

Comment: It depends if your element has a value or not, for example a div or a span don't have a value, in that case you can try innerText

Comment: Are you using `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`?  The question asks both, and they return very different things.  Can you provide a simpler [mcve] which demonstrates just the operation of trying to get a value from an input?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.Price_Container__UAUoC.AxieCard_Price__sGl3J')` is not an `input` element hence reading its `value` does not make sense!

Comment: Maybe `document.querySelector('.Price_Container__UAUoC.AxieCard_Price__sGl3J').textContent.trim()` - It will be the price text.

Comment: Should be `document.querySelector('.FiatPrice_FiatPrice__5w_aV').textContent.replace("$","")`

Answer (score 0):

Your document.querySelectorAll... works fine, but you try to get a singular value from a list of items.
You should iterate over the node list you get from querySelectorAll with a loop, like for.
Hope that helps and gives you a starting point.